# Determine the relative camera pose given two RGB camera frames in openCV-python

Tags: computer-vision, matlab, python, opencv

I would like to determine the relative camera pose given two RGB camera frames. I assume there's overlap in field of view between the two cameras, what I am looking for ultimately is the rotation and translation between two cameras. I understand how to do this in theory, and am looking for existing openCV implementations in python. An existing one for matlab can be found here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/relativecamerapose.html#inputarg_inlierPoints1. But so far as I can tell I see no openCV API in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you understand how relative pose estimation works in theory, it should be quite trivial to translate it into OpenCV code. First, you can pick any feature detection/description approach you like (say SIFT and brute force matching) and obtain a list of matches. But here, you need to be absolutely sure there is overlap between the images: because without feature matches, relative pose estimation would not work.

Once you have access to these matches (pairs of features visible in both images), you can then use the [`findEssentialMat()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findessentialmat) function in OpenCV, where you will have to provide the intrinsics data from the camera as well as those matching pairs you obtained in the first step. This function, using a RANSAC scheme will compute the essential matrix that encodes the transformation between the scenes. Once you obtain the matrix $E$, you can use another OpenCV function [`recoverPose()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#recoverpose) and pass the $E$ matrix to it, which will calculate the relative rotation (as a Rodrigues vector, if I remember right) and the relative translation up to scale.

These functions are available in C++ as well as Python. To put you on the right path about how to go about coding it in python, here is a tutorial on how to compute the fundamental matrix through feature matches in OpenCV: this can be easily extended to the essential matrix and subsequently the relative pose.

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html

Comment: what about mask for inliers and outliers?